# React onClick - pass event with parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, dom-events

### *Without Parameter*

```
function clickMe(e){
  //e is the event
}

<button onClick={this.clickMe}></button>
```

### *With Parameter*

```
function clickMe(parameter){
  //how to get the "e" ?
}
<button onClick={() => this.clickMe(someparameter)}></button>
```

I want to get the `event`. How can I get it?

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Try this:

```
<button 
   onClick={(e) => {
      this.clickMe(e, someParameter);
   }}
>
Click Me!
</button>
```

And in your function:

```
function clickMe(event, someParameter){
     //do with event
}
```

Comment: This had given me an eslint error (https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-parens.html)

What I did was wrap the function parameters in parentheses `onClick={(e) => { this.clickMe(e, someparameter) }}`

Comment: Yes @kretzm If we don't give braces, it acts as a return expression when it's single line else we must use braces to wrap as a function body.

Comment: I just want to add that it's a not recommended syntax. From the reactjs docs: _The problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created each time the button renders. In most cases, this is fine. However, if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components, those components might do an extra re-rendering. We generally recommend binding in the constructor or using the class fields syntax, to avoid this sort of performance problem._ More info at [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: @Victor. Yes you are right. But if you want the context of your parent inside your callback, you need to have different callback on each render. Actually it's a trade off I think.

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja I think the best solution is to utilize the `data-*` attributes in HTML5. Please see my answer below for more details.

Comment: @northernwind I mean they literally recommend the construction in this answer [in the next section of the docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers). When you say "it's a not recommended syntax", that's not only overstated, they, um, _do recommend it_.  The only use-case where that's bad news is "_if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components_"; in all other uses, they appear to actually encourage it. The callback-passing is good to keep in mind, but other than that, `onclick={(e) => /*...*/}` away.

Answer (score 71):

With the ES6, you can do in a shorter way like this:

```
const clickMe = (parameter) => (event) => {
    // Do something
}
```

And use it:

```
<button onClick={clickMe(someParameter)} />
```

Comment: does this also solve the creating a new callback issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597602/react-onclick-pass-event-with-parameter#comment83943132_42597619

Comment: in addition to this, you can send multiple parameter. const clickMe = (parameter1,parameter2) => (event) => {
    // Do something
}

Comment: This one is also fired when your component is mounted, your code should be: `onClick={(e) => clickMe(someParameter)(e)}`

Comment: Similarly to if just clickMe, you can also destruct the event, even u do not define it as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for this. It works. But why is there `const clickMe = (parameter) => (event) => {...}`  instead `const clickMe = (parameter) => {...}` ?

Comment: @AlexanderKim I tweaked the example you provided, it doesn't look like it fires when the component is mounted https://codesandbox.io/s/long-voice-nkn4z

Comment: @JosephCho I think you'll see it _does_ fire when mounted. Your CodeSandBox hides the fact because of the nested arrow functions. It's a little more clear if you convert to regular function https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-bhabha-lqqti

Comment: @zrna If I'm following, it's actually pretty clever. Usually you name a function and that's executed by the context (browser) that also passes in `event` as the parameter -- `onclick={myFunction}` resolves to `myFunction(event)`. This is saying "the function you want to call is the _return value_ from `clickMe(someParameter)`" -- you're calling `clickMe(someParameter)(event)`. So the first function `(parameter) =>` returns the inner function `(event) => {...}` and now you have a closure with `parameter` and `event` in scope. I think. 

Comment: @OtaniShuzo No, but [that's probably not a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597602/react-onclick-pass-event-with-parameter#comment135584237_42597619).

Answer (score 23):

**Solution 1**

```
function clickMe(parameter, event){
}

<button onClick={(event) => {this.clickMe(someparameter, event)}></button>
```

**Solution 2**
Using the bind function is considered better, than the arrow function way, in solution 1.
Note, that the event parameter should be the last parameter in the handler function

```
function clickMe(parameter, event){
}

<button onClick={this.clickMe.bind(this, someParameter)}></button>
```

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation on the solution 2?

Answer (score 16):

[Currying](https://javascript.info/currying-partials) with ES6 example:

```
const clickHandler = param => event => {
  console.log(param); // your parameter
  console.log(event.type); // event type, e.g.: click, etc.
};
```

Our button, that toggles handler:

```
<button onClick={(e) => clickHandler(1)(e)}>Click me!</button>
```

If you want to call this function expression without an event object, then you'd call it this way:

`clickHandler(1)();`

Also, since react uses synthetic events (a wrapper for native events), there's an [event pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) thing, which means, if you want to use your `event` object asynchronously, then you'd have to use `event.persist()`:

```
const clickHandler = param => event => {
  event.persist();
  console.log(event.target);
  setTimeout(() => console.log(event.target), 1000); // won't be null, otherwise if you haven't used event.persist() it would be null.
};
```

Here's live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-joliot-4eblc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Why do I still need to have ```event.persist()``` with ```console.log(event)``` but I don't need it with ```console.log(event.target)```?

Comment: Read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling

Comment: In this context, it is faster to use a normal function receiving 2 params than currying. you can run a benchmark test in jsben.ch

Comment: @ncesar How do you setup React in jsben.ch?  Post your test plz.

Comment: @IsaacPak jsben is a simple tool to test javascript codes. You pretty much place two different samples of code and compare their speed. You don't have to put your entire React code, just a function that you think may be slower and you want to test. Also, I always use jsben.ch and jsbench.me just to make sure.

In the clickHandler context, you would need to mock some codes. Like ``let event;`` so it wont throw an undefined error.

Comment: I use jsben.ch all the time, but never used it to test React components.  I was asking for an example because I'd like to know how it's done...

Comment: he probably didnt use react, just tested passing two parameters using currying  vs passing two parameters at the same time

Answer (score 8):

To solve the creating new callback issue completely, utilize the `data-*` attributes in HTML5 is the best solution IMO.
Since in the end of the day, even if you extract a sub-component to pass the parameters, it still creates new functions.

For example,

```
const handleBtnClick = e => {
  const { id } = JSON.parse(e.target.dataset.onclickparam);
  // ...
};

<button onClick={handleBtnClick} data-onclickparam={JSON.stringify({ id: 0 })}>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes for using `data-*` attributes.