# React: ProgressiveMobileStepper handleNext function does not work (Material UI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Dear community I am currently writing a website and its user onboarding using the ProrgressiveMobileStepper using Material UI. You can find my website here: 
https://konekto-eeioq6hwh.now.sh/first_use

Apart from the formatting being screwed up (for which I would also appreciate your help), I am mainly concerned that the next button does not work. I have structured that the several screens are conditionally rendered in index.js depending on the state and the handleNext function should be called from ProgressiveMobileStepper when the button is clicked. However, the screen does not update then.

> index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid, Container } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Header } from '../Layout';
import logo from './android-icon-192x192.png';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import ExplanationAboutProcess0 from './Explanation0';
import ExplanationAboutProcess1 from './ExplanationProcess1';
import ExplanationAboutProcess2 from './ExplanationProcess2';
import ExplanationAboutProcess3 from './ExplanationProcess3';
import ProgressiveMobileStepper from './ProgressiveMobileStepper';

const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    border: 'black',
    'border-width': 'medium',
    'margin-top': '80px',
    background: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)',
    'border-radius': '20px'
  },
  picture: { display: 'block', margin: '0 auto' },
  box: { width: '230px' }
});
class FirstUse extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.classes = props.classes;
    this.state = {
      componentType: 'explanationaboutprocess0'
    };
    this.handleNext = this.handleNext.bind(this);
    this.handleBack = this.handleBack.bind(this);
  }
  fun() {
    //this.props.history.push('/settings');
  }

  handleNext(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(this.componentType);
    if (this.componentType == 'explanationaboutprocess0')
      this.setState({ componentType: 'explanationaboutprocess1' });
  }

  handleBack(e) {
    console.log(e);
    if (this.componentType == 'explanationaboutprocess1')
      this.setState({ componentType: 'explanationaboutprocess0' });
  }
  render() {
    let component;
    if (this.state.componentType == 'explanationaboutprocess0') {
      component = (
        <ExplanationAboutProcess0
          handleNext={this.handleNext}
          handleBack={this.handleBack}
        />
      );
    } else if (this.state.componentType == 'explanationaboutprocess1') {
      component = (
        <ExplanationAboutProcess1
          handleComponentType={this.handleComponentType}
          handleBack={this.handleBack}
        />
      );
    } else if (this.state.componentType == 'explanationaboutprocess2') {
      component = (
        <ExplanationAboutProcess2
          handleComponentType={this.handleComponentType}
          handleBack={this.handleBack}
        />
      );
    } else if (this.state.componentType == 'explanationaboutprocess3') {
      component = (
        <ExplanationAboutProcess3
          handleComponentType={this.handleComponentType}
          handleBack={this.handleBack}
        />
      );
    }
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Header title="Learn how to send SOS" />
        <Grid
          container
          className={this.classes.container}
          direction="column"
          spacing={2}
        >
          <Grid item sm={12} className={this.classes.item}>
            <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item sm={12} className={this.classes.item} />
          <Container component="main" maxWidth="sm">
            {component}
          </Container>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm={12} className={this.classes.item}>
          <ProgressiveMobileStepper />
        </Grid>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(FirstUse);
```

> ProgressiveMobileStepper.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import MobileStepper from '@material-ui/core/MobileStepper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import KeyboardArrowLeft from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowLeft';
import KeyboardArrowRight from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowRight';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    maxWidth: 400,
    flexGrow: 1
  }
});

export default function ProgressMobileStepper(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <MobileStepper
      variant="progress"
      steps={6}
      position="static"
      className={classes.root}
      nextButton={
        <Button
          size="small"
          onClick={props.handleNext}
          disabled={activeStep === 5}
        >
          Next
          {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? (
            <KeyboardArrowLeft />
          ) : (
            <KeyboardArrowRight />
          )}
        </Button>
      }
      backButton={
        <Button
          size="small"
          onClick={props.handleBack}
          disabled={activeStep === 0}
        >
          {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? (
            <KeyboardArrowRight />
          ) : (
            <KeyboardArrowLeft />
          )}
          Back }
        </Button>
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Just as an example, you can see two of the screens, which should be conditionally rendered below:

> Explanation0.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core';

export default class ExplanationAboutProcess1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.classes = props.classes;
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Typography>
          Konnekto allows you to send an emergency request from you phone
          without requiring a celluar connection. Please enter your personal
          information.
        </Typography>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

> ExplanationProcess1.js file:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ExplanationAboutProcess1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.classes = props.classes;
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <p>
          To explain you how you would use the app in case of emergency, we
          guide you through which questions we ask you:
          <br />
          0.1 Are you affected yourself?
          <br />
          0.2 How do you want to contact?
        </p>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React onClick - pass event with parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42597602/react-onclick-pass-event-with-parameter)

Comment: I don´t think it is a duplicate. Why would I need an event an a parameter in my onClick function?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you're trying to console log it in your `handleNext` function.  Try `onClick={() => props.handleNext}`.